# Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, async-await, axios

So, I'm building a mern stack project on an E-Learning clone and I'm stuck with this error:
Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

code at client side:

```
const handleSubmit=async(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.table({name, email, type, password, condition});
    const {data} =await axios.post("http://localhost:3002/api/register", {name, email, type, password, condition})
    console.log("Response from front end", data)
}
```

code at server side:

```
(async () => {
fs.readdirSync("./routes").map((r)=>app.use("api", require(`./routes/${r}`)))
})
```

What can be the cause of error here. Can anyone help me? I've already tried many things.

Comment: looks like you are trying to use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) on the server side code but forgot to put the calling parenthesis `()` at the end to actually call the function. is this just a typo?

Comment: @about14sheep after doing that, it shows this error: 
ReferenceError: require is not defined. and im using node-fetch@2.6.1.
Also, earlier the server was running and database also got connected but now even the server is not running due to error.

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file? and is the file extension `.mjs` or `.js`?